# Collision(Duplication ) while Random shuffle of array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of n integers.
I need to shuffle the array in some random order multiple times during m iterations of the program.

I mean for each of m iterations, the array of n integers needs to be shuffled .

What I do is that I pass an input and an output array of n integers each with the input containing 1 to n and output contains same numbers but in shuffled order.

However the issue I am getting with my code is that consecutive shuffles collide and return same shuffled array .

like if its

`1,54,7,11,13,.....` 
in 1st iteration then even in 2nd and 3rd iterations i get the same order ie
`1,54,7,11,13,.....` 
`1,54,7,11,13,.....`

and again in 4th iteration a new order appears but repeats for next 2,3 iterations
`23,1,4,6,76,11,......`
`23,1,4,6,76,11,......`

whereas my requirement is that each time the shuffling should be unique.
My shuffling function code is pasted below

```
void ShufflingUtility::randomShuffle(int inputArray[],int size,int returnArray[])
{
       srand(time(0));

       std::random_shuffle(&inputArray[0], &inputArray[size]);
       for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
       {
           returnArray[j] = inputArray[j];
       }
}
```

Any suggestion to resolve this duplication issue is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: First of all, the `srand` function should be called only *once* in a program, as it resets the seed. That could lead to you using the same sequence multiple calls to `randomShuffle`. Secondly, the [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) function was deprecated in the C++14 standard, and removed in the C++17 standard. Use `std::shuffle` instead, together with the new [PRNG functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) introduced in C++11.

Comment: If `randomShuffle` executes multiple times within one second, `srand(time(0));` will cause each execution to have the same seed, and therefore produces the same output.

Comment: Note that the [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) overload you are using was deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. It should not be used in new code. Consider using the modern [random number generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) alternatives.

Comment: `srand(time(0));` is your bug. Remember that the resolution of time is 1 second so calling this more than 1 time in the same second should result in the same shuffling.